# Call Cubepoints Rank For Buddypress In Functions

Tags: buddypress

There's a function to call cubepoints points for buddypress under groups topic.php posted by a good friend on stackoverflow here:

```
 add_filter('bp_get_the_topic_time_since_last_post','bp_forum_extras_get_the_topic_time_since_last_post');

add_action('bp_get_the_topic_post_poster_avatar', 'topic_poster_avatar');
function topic_poster_avatar($avatar) {
preg_match_all('/user-([0-9]+)-avatar/', $avatar, $m);
$id = $m[1][0];
if ($count = get_user_meta($id, 'cpoints', 1))
    return $avatar . '<div class="cp-avatar-counter"><center><span class="number">' . $count . '</span> Points</center></div>';
return $avatar;
```

}

I wanted to know if you knew the function to call cubepoints ranks as a function for buddypress? The code below is used for BB press not buddypress. cp_module_ranks_getRank should be used to call cubepoints rank but how would I make that into a function like above?

```
<?php echo cp_module_ranks_getRank( bp_displayed_user_id() ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If we don't know where you want to call it, we can't suggest a hook or filter.

I'm guessing you want it in the BP members loop ? 
If so, look at the do_action hooks in that template, write a function and return the results of cp_module_ranks_getRank( bp_get_member_user_id() ).

Comment: Tried this -> add_filter('bp_get_the_topic_time_since_last_post','bp_forum_extras_get_the_topi‌​c_time_since_last_post'); add_action('bp_get_the_topic_post_poster_avatar', 'topic_poster_avatar');function topic_poster_avatar($avatar) {
    preg_match_all('/user-([0-9]+)-avatar/', $avatar, $m);
    $id = $m[1][0];
    if ($count = get_user_meta($id, 'cpoints', 1))
        return $avatar . if(function_exists('cp_module_ranks_getRank')) && $user->ID){ echo '<div class="cp-avatar-counter"><span class="cupepoints_buddypress_rank">'.cp_module_ranks_getRank($count).'</span>‌​</div>'; return $avatar; }